# Static files urls pointing to Django instead of to nginx

Tags: django, nginx

I'm trying to serve static files with nginx for my Django app.

I'm following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn) in which they propose the following nginx config file:

```
server {
    server_name yourdomainorip.com;

    access_log off;

    location /static/ {
        alias /opt/myenv/static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
    }
}
```

And in my settings.py I have the following declarations:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

I'm able to see the static files at urls of the form:

```
http://x.x.x.x/static/admin/img/icon_searchbox.png
```

However, when trying to reference static files in my templates using the {% static %} tag, I get urls of the form:

```
http://x.x.x.x:8001/static/admin/img/icon_searchbox.png
```

which doesn't point to the files and instead are procesed by Django.

Any ideas of how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

It was missing the first `"/"`

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo. The first "/" is present in my settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this config for nginx:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```